# What organisms ranging from 0.2 - 4 mm lend themselves to domestication? (Series)

Tags: domestication

- As a continuation of my [two](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37378/how-could-a-race-of-microscopic-humanoid-organisms-benefit-from-the-domesticatio) [previous](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37046/does-any-microorganism-lend-itself-to-domestication) questions about domestication*

What animals that can be found in gardens and range from 0.2 mm - 4 mm could be a possible candidate for domestication to a race of tiny humanoids?

Comment: ok, my curiosity is getting the better of my: would you mind explaining the sudden influx of questions about microscopic life? youve asked something like seven or eight in the last few days by my count; are you writing a story or something? i, for one, would be pretty interesting in reading it, based off of the questions youve asked.

Comment: @DuncanUrquhart That , my dear asker of questions , is precisely what I am doing. I tried this once , but to my dismay there is a stark lack of speculative questions about microscopic people on the web .So you know what they say , if you want something done ( right ) you must do it yourself . ( and thank for the compliment , it is much appreciated )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are a little above your size range, given that they grow up to 6mm, but [aphids](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Aphids.aspx) already *have* been [domesticated by ants](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2007/10/071009212548.htm) in the real world:

> Scientists had previously established that certain types of aphids
>   live in colonies where they are used as a food source by a
>   neighbouring colony of ants. The ants have been known to bite the
>   wings off the aphids in order to stop them from getting away and
>   depriving the ants of one of their staple foods: the sugar-rich sticky
>   honeydew which is excreted by aphids when they eat plants. Chemicals
>   produced in the glands of ants can also sabotage the growth of aphid
>   wings. The new study shows, for the first time, that ants' chemical
>   footprints -- which are already known to be used by ants to mark out
>   their territory - also play a key role in manipulating the aphid
>   colony, and keeping it nearby.